# Why am i getting a TLE in this question on some cases?

Tags: c++, templates

https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/c-class-templates/problem.
This is the link to the problem.
I have used basic template concept and basic template specialization.
Here's the code:

```
template<class T>
class AddElements{

    T a;
    public:
    AddElements(T x)
    {
        a=x;
    }
    T add(T y)
    {
        return a+y;
    };
};
template<>
class AddElements<string>{

    string x;
    public:
    AddElements(string a)
    {
        x=a;
    }
    string concatenate(string b)
    {

        return x+b;
    };
};

int main () {
  int n,i;
  cin >> n;
  for(i=0;i<n;i++) {
    string type;
    cin >> type;
    if(type=="float") {
        double element1,element2;
        cin >> element1 >> element2;
        AddElements<double> myfloat (element1);
        cout << myfloat.add(element2) << endl;
    }
    else if(type == "int") {
        int element1, element2;
        cin >> element1 >> element2;
        AddElements<int> myint (element1);
        cout << myint.add(element2) << endl;
    }
    else if(type == "string") {
        string element1, element2;
        cin >> element1 >> element2;
        AddElements<string> mystring (element1);
        cout << mystring.concatenate(element2) << endl;
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

It's giving TLE for some cases and i don't know why.

Comment: Please add all information into your question. Don't link to necessary information.

Comment: What are the testcases?

Comment: You are passing the arguments by value. Try to pass a const ref.

Comment: If the input data is not trustworthy, the code is not checking for failed input.

Comment: Usually you can ignore TLE. It seems to depend on the current workload of the machine. I ran the same code 10 times and each time other test cases failed with TLE. One hour later all testcases were successful with the same code.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing the arguments by value. Try to pass a const ref or use references.

Usually you can ignore TLE. It seems to depend on the current workload of the machine. I ran the same code 10 times and each time other test cases failed with TLE. One hour later all testcases were successful with the same code.

```
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdio>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cassert>
using namespace std;

template<class T>
class AddElements{

    T a;
    public:
    AddElements(T x) : a(x) {}
    T add(T y) {
        return a + y;
    }
};

template<>
class AddElements<string>{

    string &a;
    public:
    AddElements(string &x) : a(x) {}
    string concatenate(string &y) {
        return a.append(y);
    }
};

int main () {
  int n,i;
  cin >> n;
  for(i=0;i<n;i++) {
    string type;
    cin >> type;
    if(type=="float") {
        double element1,element2;
        cin >> element1 >> element2;
        AddElements<double> myfloat (element1);
        cout << myfloat.add(element2) << endl;
    }
    else if(type == "int") {
        int element1, element2;
        cin >> element1 >> element2;
        AddElements<int> myint (element1);
        cout << myint.add(element2) << endl;
    }
    else if(type == "string") {
        string element1, element2;
        cin >> element1 >> element2;
        AddElements<string> mystring (element1);
        cout << mystring.concatenate(element2) << endl;
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

With this code all testcases were successful now. One hour ago some testcases failed.